# Only create case if configured mail address is in the TO

Tags: email2case

We have configured email to case in Salesforce with the address mail@case.com (dummy of course). Now our customer is asking if we can block case creation if the that address (mail@case.com ) is in the CC field of the incoming mail and not in the TO field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion will be to use 3rd party email forwarder based on your rule (for CC -- forward to your email-to-case rule)

Comment: If I understand correctly you would put this kind of logic in the email forwarder and not in Salesforce, correct?

Comment: yes, absolutely correct

Comment: you confirm what I already thought. If you post it as an answer I'll gladly mark it as correct :)